# Java silently failing to print from array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printf

I'm trying to convert an integer into an array of digits, then print those digits out in order. It's an early problem in Java: How to Program, and I'm confused as to why I can't make it work.

Here's my class:

```
public class AnyDigits {
    private int[] ns;

    public AnyDigits(int n){
        this.ns = new int[String.valueOf(n).length()];
        for(int i = 0, x = n; x > 0; i++, x = x / 10){
            this.ns[i] = x % 10;
        }
    }
    public void printDigits(){
        for(int i = this.ns.length - 1; i == 0; i--){
            System.out.printf("%d ", this.ns[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code in my main method:

```
AnyDigits digitsTest = new AnyDigits(42339);
digitsTest.printDigits();
```

Any comments on the organisation, style and formatting of my code are also welcomed.

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = this.ns.length - 1; i == 0; i--){
    System.out.printf("%d ", this.ns[i]);
}
```

This won't work, you are iterating while `i==0`, `i` will never be `0` at the first loop unless `this.ns.length == 1`.

You need

```
for(int i = this.ns.length - 1; i != 0; i--){
    System.out.printf("%d ", this.ns[i]);
}
```

or

```
for(int i = this.ns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.printf("%d ", this.ns[i]);
}
```

---

Anyway, if you want to print an array, you can just do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));
```

Comment: Ack, I should've known it would be something stupid on my part. Thanks a ton, and I'll be over here trying to salvage my dignity.

Comment: @JamesDuval Haha, no dignity lost, everyone can do errors if they aren't familiar with the language they are using!

Comment: the >= version is safer. Less chance for accidental infinite loops if i is ever manipulated in the loop.

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, it definitely is!

Answer (score 2):

Another way aside from BackSlash's answer-

```
private static int[] makeArrayFromInt(final int val){

    String temp = String.valueOf(val);

    int[] digits = new int[temp.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
        digits[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(i, i + 1));
    }

    return digits;

}
```

Test:

```
int[] digits = makeArrayFromInt(12234);
for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++){
    System.out.println(digits[i]);
}
```

Comment: Cheers. In this particular case, under the terms of the exercise, I had to use the modulus/modulo operator, but I really appreciate seeing a different approach to the same problem.